# First list disappears in recycler view disappears

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that shows different lists depending on which option I pick in my `Spinner`. I can add items to a list dynamically, but when I add items to the top option on the `Spinner`, two items appear everytime I add, when it is only supposed to add just one and when I choose a different option in the `Spinner` and then back to the top option, all items that are supposed to be in it are gone. However, when I repeat the same actions in another option, one item is added at a time, and they are still there if i switch to another and back, so it is only in the first option where I experience these problems.

Here are pictures that shows what happens. First picture shows the entire `Spinner`, second is the top option selected with items added, third is the second `Spinner` option selected and fourth is back to the top option and now the items are gone.

[image: Babou]
[image: Babou]
[image: Babou]
[image: Babou]

This method is used to add a Item to one of the lists. Each option in the `Spinner` is used to get an element in `listOfLists` where each element is an `ArrayList<Item>()`. `mItemList` is the list which the `RecyclerView` prints out.

```
  public void addItem(){
        mItemList.add(0, new Item(idText.getText().toString(), addAmountField.getText().toString()));
        listOfLists.get(dropdown.getSelectedItemPosition()).add(0, new Item(idText.getText().toString(), addAmountField.getText().toString()));
        System.out.println("ListSize: " + listOfLists.get(dropdown.getSelectedItemPosition()).size());

        addAmountField.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        saveData2();
    }
```

This is the code for switching the lists when I choose another option from the `Spinner`. What I do here is that I clear the `mItemList` and then I fill it with one of the `ArrayList<Item>` inside `listOfLists`.

```
 dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                mItemList.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < listOfLists.get(position).size(); i++) {
                    mItemList.add(listOfLists.get(position).get(i));
                }


                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

        });
```

How can I resolve this so that the top option of the `Spinner` will work just like the other options where it adds one item at a time and still has the items after I switch to another option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it so for anyone who faces similar problems this was the problem:

Unlike the other lists in listOfLists where I set mItemList to the chosen list like this

```
 mItemList.clear();

 for (int i = 0; i < listOfLists.get(position).size(); i++) {
      mItemList.add(listOfLists.get(position).get(i));
 }
```

mItemList is always set to the first list when I run the app like this

```
mItemList = listOfLists.get(dropDown.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

So I just changed it so it sets mItemList the same way it is done with the other lists and now it is working.